# git mv command with Xcode, resource in Xcode disappears?

Tags: xcode, git

I'm trying to go through some git commands and tutorials so I don't have to use Xcode for source control.  I tried a simple example with a picture.

- I dragged a picture 0000.jpg into my project.
- I see the picture 0000.jpg has an "A" next to it in Xcode
- I go to the command line and git commit -m "test"
- git mv 0000.jpg 1.jpg
- git commit -m "message"

When I go to the folder where this image lies, I do see it gets changed to 1.jpg.  However, in Xcode, I still see the image named as 0000.jpg.  Even if I clean the project and close and reopen Xcode, the name stays the same.  Am I missing something with the mv command?  Or is Xcode just not doing what it's supposed to be doing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode is not aware of file system changes like renaming a file. You have to readd the file inside of your project or rename it inside of Xcode.

This is unlike Eclipse and some other Java IDEs you may have used.